# how to build web service that get post method

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c

I am regular to send from my iphone to a web service a URL with all the data and i want to know if there is any way to get this stuff by sending this data with post method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you don't give much detail on your needs, or what you have, I'll give you some broad resources:

[Consuming WCF / REST service using JQuery ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348128/consuming-wcf-rest-service-using-jquery-ajax-post)

[WebInvoke Method=“POST” or "GET" for a REST Service on WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197956/webinvoke-method-post-or-get-for-a-rest-service-on-wcf)

[Get raw xml from POST method in service implemented using WCF WebHttp API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584872/get-raw-xml-from-post-method-in-service-implemented-using-wcf-webhttp-api)

If you need more specific help, please include more details regarding your needs and what code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find MVC to provide a nice and organized way of publishing REST APIs. for example if you want a REST method that returns the time base on an offset on post you would create something like this

```
public class TimeController: Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetTime(int offset)
        {
           return new JsonResult { Time= DateTime.Now().AddHours(offset) };
        }
}
```

you can access that action if you post to `http://appurl/TimeController/GetTime`